# Use result of cat function to select value from a named vector in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make the following piece of code work:

```
named_vector[[cat('"',1720,'"', sep = "")]]
```

But always get the same error message, as below:

```
> named_vector[[cat('"',1720,'"', sep = "")]]
"1720"Error in exchange_test_named[[cat("\"", 1720, "\"", sep = "")]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

Now, however, if I run the code within the square brackets separately and pop the result into the brackets the code works perfectly well:

```
cat('"',1720,'"', sep = "")

> cat('"',1720,'"', sep = "")
"1720"

named_vector[["1720"]]

> named_vector[["1720"]]
[1] 2516
```

Why does it not work if the `cat` function is nested within square brackets?

*For the sake of completeness:* I use this operation for a function that converts historical cash values into silver values based on historical exchange rates, which I stored in the lookup tables `named_vector` and `named_vector2`. I use separate tables before and after 1912 for historical reasons.

```
convert_cash <- function(year, cash) {

  result <- case_when(
  ({{year}} <= 1912) == TRUE ~ {{cash}}/unname(named_vector[[cat('"',{{year}},'"', sep = "")]]),
  
(1912 <= {{year}} && {{year}} <= 1949) == TRUE ~ {{cash}}/unname(named_vector2[[cat('"',{{year}},'"', sep = "")]]),
  
is.na({{year}}) == TRUE || is.na({{year}}) == TRUE ~ 0
  )

print(result)

}
```

Comment: Use paste0() instead. cat() return value is NULL, it just prints.

Comment: That works beautifully, thanks!